# how to see branches in my remote origin?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have two remote origins for my project. I did like this when I already have one origin
`git remote add github https://github.com/iincube/Commuter.git`
then my project have two remote origins like this

```
github  https://github.com/iincube/Commuter.git (fetch)
```

github  https://github.com/iincube/Commuter.git (push)

origin  https://github.com/iincube/SafetraxApp.git (fetch)

origin  https://github.com/iincube/SafetraxApp.git (push)

now if I am doing $git branch I can see only one remote branches only.
How can I see both remote branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the following command:

```
git branch -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command:

```
git branch --all
```